# iOS Notification Dev Environment: how do you properly set up APNS?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning

I am interested in setting up iOS push notifications in my dev environment (push notifications currently work in prod).  My dev and prod apps use different bundle identifiers, as widely suggested: https://medium.com/@danielgalasko/run-multiple-versions-of-your-app-on-the-same-device-using-xcode-configurations-1fd3a220c608

```
Prod: com.MyApp
Dev:  com.MyApp.dev
```

For prod and dev, do I need to create a separate APNS key? Other Stack Overflow answers suggested you could use the same key - but I've struggled with this. When configuring your APNS key, setup states: "One key is used for all of your apps."  However, later, the page also mentions: "Each App ID requires its own Client SSL Certificate."

Answer (score 1):

My confusion was over APNS key vs. APNS Certificate:

You can re-use the APNS key, but you need to create a new certificate for each new app/bundle ID.